# Visual Studio 2010: Opening a file using command line resets window layout

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, command-line

The following command works fine. It opens a new instance of Visual Studio 2010:

```
devenv
```

But if I specify a file name, Visual Studio's window layout will be reset.

```
devenv "D:\Temp\test.txt"
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

---

**Update:**

This command works:

```
devenv /command "open D:\Temp\test.txt"
```

But the file path cannot contain spaces. The following command gives an error: "The operation cannot be completed. The system cannot find the file specified":

```
devenv /command "open D:\Temp\test 2.txt"
```

I tried:

```
devenv /command "open 'D:\Temp\test 2.txt'"
```

But got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I think understand now.

Visual Studio uses different layouts for different situations. It uses a special layout when it is opened from command line with a specified file name.

I have never custom this layout so it looks like the default one, made me thought the layout was reset.